# Перетаскивание элемента SVG поверх другого элемента SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть ли способ перетащить элемент `SVG` поверх другого `SVG` элемента ?

Я попытался,  как в этом уроке но, я могу перетащить только тот, который я поставил вторым сверху над первым.

Я не могу перетащить первый квадрат за второй без проблем. Кто-нибудь знает, как это решить?

Вот полный `tutorial`: http://archive.petercollingridge.co.uk/book/export/html/437

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Dragging SVG element over another SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29212899/7394871) от участника  [@user3047561](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3047561/user3047561).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/29212899/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Итак, вот пример решения с комментариями внутри кода:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="200">
    
    <style>
      .draggable {
        cursor: move;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var selectedElement = 0;
    var currentX = 0;
    var currentY = 0;
    var currentMatrix = 0;

 function cloneToTop(oldEl){
   // already at top, don't go farther…
   if(oldEl.atTop==true) return oldEl;
   // делаем копию этого узла
   var el = oldEl.cloneNode(true);
    //выберите все перетаскиваемые элементы, ни один из них не находится наверху
   var dragEls= oldEl.ownerDocument.documentElement.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
   for(i=0; i<dragEls.length; i++){
    dragEls[i].atTop=null;
    }
   var parent = oldEl.parentNode;
   // удалить исходный узел
   parent.removeChild(oldEl);
   // вставьте наш новый узел сверху (последний нарисованный элемент сначала отображается в svg)
     parent.appendChild(el);
     // Скажите миру, что наш новый элемент наверху
   el.atTop= true;
   return el;
   }


    function selectElement(evt) {
      selectedElement = cloneToTop(evt.target);
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
      currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7,-1).split(' ');
    
      for(var i=0; i<currentMatrix.length; i++) {
        currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
      }
      
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
    }
        
    function moveElement(evt) {
      var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
      var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
      currentMatrix[4] += dx;
      currentMatrix[5] += dy;
      
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
    }
        
    function deselectElement(evt) {
      if(selectedElement != 0){
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
          selectedElement = 0;
          }
        }
        
    ]]> </script>
    <g>
    <circle/>
    </g>

    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="399" height="199" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
    
    <rect class="draggable" id="blue" x="30" y="30" width="80" height="80" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 46 18)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>
          
    <rect class="draggable" id="green" x="160" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 51 11)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Dragging SVG element over another SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214601/7394871) от участника  [@https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido).</sub>